# Trying to install ruby 1.9.3 with rbenv

Tags: ruby, terminal, homebrew, rbenv, bash

I have just reformatted mt machine, so I am starting from scratch here. I installed home brew than brew update than brew doctor than i ran the following before for rbenv

```
$ brew update
$ brew install rbenv
$ brew install ruby-build
```

bash_profile

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/anderskitson/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:subli
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Althought when I run rbenv install 1.9.3-p327 I get `env: bash: No such file or directory`
I have also installed xcode with command line tools.
Help!

Comment: your second `export` is missing `$PATH` itself. But not sure if that is the solution.

Comment: @pduersteler dont thinks so those top two were for launching a symlink I created for sublime text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to include $PATH in each of those lines in your .bash_profile otherwise you'll lose the default paths (including /bin, which is where bash is installed by default on OS X).

As this stands, without $PATH on the second line of your .bash_profile, you're completely overwriting your previous path with "/usr/local/bin:subli". Then the third line adds "$HOME/.rbenv/bin" in addition to that, but you're still going to be missing things like /bin, /usr/bin, etc.

I would go ahead and make sure that you are including $PATH in all three of those lines so that you add to, rather than replace, your existing path.